# How to make dynamic @yield in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make `@yield('dynamic')` to load different pages like single page application in laravel.

Route:

```
Route::get(
    '/front-office-setup/{setup_type}',
    'AdmissionFrontOfficeSetupController@index'
)->name('frontofficesetupview');
```

Controller:

```
public function index($setup_type)
{
    $data['setup_type'] = $setup_type;

    return view('frontoffice::frontofficesetup.frontofficesetup', $data);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">asdf</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">asdf</div>
    <div class="col-md-5"> @yield('{{$setup_type}}')</div>
</div>
```

Section:

```
@extends('frontoffice::frontofficesetup.frontofficesetup')
@section('visitor-purpose')
sdfasd
@endsection
```

But it doesn't render or show in `@yield('{{$setup_type}}')`

Is there any way to do this?

**Edit part***
Also i have already included a @yield type of things in view file

```
@extends('backend.master.master')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">asdf</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">asdf</div>
    <div class="col-md-5"> @yield($setup_type)</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: It looks like in your controller you are rendering a view that is extending itself (or maybe you are calling the master layout itself). Also as @Sahil mentioned in his answer, there is no need for {{ }} inside the yield

Answer (score 3):

@yield is already started PHP tag `<?php`. SO no need to mention braces again`{{}}`. Simply try `@yield($setup_type)` It will work perfectly.

Comment: Was a very helpful information but still it doesn't show....Did i do any mistake up there? when i simply do {{$setup_type}} it shows me passed data

Comment: What is the value of sertup_type?

Comment: visitor-purpose

Comment: Can you please name the view files in your question?